# The meaning of "The evening was voted a great success."

Tags: meaning

The evening was voted a great success.

I don't understand what does this sentence mean.

1. Everybody agreed that the evening was a great success.
2. The result of the election was a great success in the evening.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly in the sentence is confusing you? Please look up the words that are confusing you in a dictionary and [edit] if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: If your confusion about the sentence involves the fact that it doesn't specify **who** voted the evening a great success, the source of your confusion is the sentence's use of passive voice. If your confusion is just as severe when you read this sentence—"Participants at the event voted the evening a great success"—the problem lies in your understanding of figurative use of the verb _vote_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**success** [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/success) in the sense of this question:

> Meaning "**accomplishment of desired end**" (good success) first
>   recorded 1580s.

**vote** in the sense of this question:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vote)

> To express a choice or an opinion

Your sample sentence #1 is appropriate:

> Everybody agreed [voted] that the evening was a great success
>   [accomplishment of desired end].

Comment: Based on the OP’s options it seems that the question is about how ‘evening’ and ‘voted’ should be applied.  Both options seem to treat ‘success’ in the same way.

Comment: @Jim so edited ... bedtime for this bonzo!